# using namespace & overloaded function

Tags: c++, namespaces

I don't understand why I get the error "ambiguous call to overloaded function".
Before "main", I declared to use namespace "second".
My expected output is:

> this is the first foo
>   this is the second foo
>   this is the second foo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first {
    void foo() {
        cout << "this is the first foo" << endl;
    }
}

namespace second {
    void foo() {
        cout << "this is the second foo" << endl;
    }
}


void foo() {
    cout << "this is just foo" << endl;
}


using namespace second;
void main() {
    first::foo();
    second::foo();
    foo();
}
```

Comment: You have two `foos` in your namespace. You should now either use ```::foo()``` or ```second::foo()```.

Comment: You expectation is wrong. When you declare`using namespace second` you extend the working namespace with `second`. To clarify from what initial workspace you want to call a function, you should use `<namepspace>::foo`, the global namespace has empty name.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace ...` [See this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before "main", I declared to use namespace "second".

When you do this, `second::foo` is introduced into the global namespace, then for `foo();` both `second::foo` and `::foo` are valid candidates.

You can specify that you want to call the global `foo` explicitly, i.e.

```
::foo();
```

Or use [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) inside `main()` instead of [using-directive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives), e.g.

```
int main() {
    using second::foo;
    first::foo();
    second::foo();
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because of your: `using namespace second;`

When you do this you qualify the function `foo()` from the `second` namespace into the global scope. In the global scope, there exists another function `foo()` with the exact same signature. Now, your calls to `first::foo()` and `second::foo()` are fine. However, when you get to your call to `foo()`, the compiler doesn't know whether it should call just `foo()` or `second::foo()` since they are ambiguous, and at this point they are both in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your `using namespace second;` is precisely the reason you get the error. It practically tells the compiler to treat `second::foo` as if it was in the global namespace. So now you have two `foo`s there.

By the way, `void main` is not valid C++. It must be `int main`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, replace `void main() {  }` with

```
int main() {

 return 0;
}
```

Secondly, `using namespace second;` should be inside `main()` from where you want to call particular `namespace`, not globally.

Finally, If you are using `::scope resolution operator` then you don't have to mention `using namespace second` in the main(), use either one.

Just do like below

```
int main() {
        first::foo(); /* first foo will be called */
        second::foo(); /* second foo() will be called */
        foo(); /* global foo() will be called */
        return 0;
}
```